# How can i append a new row to the existing conversation without refreshing the page using ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a tr with attribute as a unique id. How do i add a new tr when a user from another account replies and i can see the reply without refreshing the page?

Comment: your question is extremely vague. Please improve your question first! Maybe with a little code snippet?

Answer (score 1):

didnt get ya completely but to append a new tr to a specific tr you can use

```
$('#trUniqueId').append(
      $('<tr/>').attr("id","newtrId")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(‘ tblDoc tr:last’).after(

 "<tr><td  style=’width:150px;’>value1</td><td  style=’width: 150px’>value2</td><td  style=’width: 150px’></td></tr>"


);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alfred is correct, your question is very vague.

However, to add a new row (newID) after the existing row (uniqueID), use the following code:

$('#uniqueID').after('<tr id="newID">' + CELL CONTENT + '</tr>');

As for pulling in the information via Ajax, we'll need to see code samples.